# how to read only particular no of bytes/characters from a line and go to the next line?

Tags: java, linux

I have developed a custom task manager in java for linux. I am writing the required content to a file and displaying it on a msgbox. But I want the Process names, PID, Session name, Session#, tty to be displayed separately. For which, i  have to read a few bytes/chars from the first column and skip to the next line to read the next few bytes/chars. How do I do this? Please help since I am new to java.
Thankz

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You have to read the entire line and process only the parts you're interested in.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you can create a matrix where each line is a line in the file and each column is one field. For example `data[4][PROCESS_NAME]` will be the process name found on line 4 (5 if counting from 0). Of course `PROCESS_NAME` comes from a `final int PROCESS_NAME = 0;` declaration.

Comment: Yes, I shall read the entire line and take the bytes/chars i will require. But how do I do it? Any method?